# How to set database time zone in application.ini

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have an application in Zend Framework that has to run for a different time zone than the server. Is there an option to set the database server (MySQL in this case) time zone in application.ini?

My current options are:

```
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "usernam"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.params.dbname = "databasename"
```

I know I can do something like `SET timezone = 'Europe/London'`, but I really need to do it in the config file.

**EDIT**

Googling around I found that `resources.db.params.driver_options.1002` should be setting the value for `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`.

Therefore `resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8, time_zone = 'Europe/London'"` *should* do the trick.  But no luck so far.

**FINAL EDIT**

Found it.
After a lot of searching and debugging I found the following code at Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php

```
if (!empty($this->_config['charset'])) {
    $initCommand = "SET NAMES '" . $this->_config['charset'] . "'";
    $this->_config['driver_options'][1002] = $initCommand; // 1002 = PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND
}
```

As I have `resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"` in my application.ini, it was overwriting `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`.

Deleting that line solved it.

Comment: Different than the web server, or different than the MySQL server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm answering my own question just to close this, as the response is already in one of the edits.

```
resources.db.params.charset
```

and

```
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002
```

as I had in my application.ini cannot be used together, as `resources.db.params.charset` ovewirites `driver_options.1002`.

If you need to set the timezone, remove `resources.db.params.charset` and pass the timezone in the charset in `driver_options`.
E.g.:

```
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8, time_zone = 'Europe/London'"
```

Comment: What if when I set up anything else in "SET NAMES 'utf8'" it returns 503 error?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES 'utf8', CHARACTER SET 'utf8', time_zone = 'Europe/London'"
```

Answer (score 3):

you might as well consider adding it on your bootstrap:

```
<?php 
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {
    protected function _initTimeZone() {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    }
}
```

Comment: date_default_timezone_set set the timezone for php, not the mysql server.  That would be equivalent to: phpSettings.date.timezone = 'Asia/Manila' in application.ini

Answer (score 0):

Try build pre dispatch plugin and get data from config file for query