# Set time zone is not optimized

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, mysqli

I use `SET time_zone = '+01:00'` in my php program,

when I benchmark my code and use `microseconds()` to get running time of my queries, I found this query take about 7 seconds!

`7.0999999999932E-5 microseconds`

I use `mysqli`, I want to know is there any better way to set time zone in my php program ?

Comment: Doesn't that say .00007099...  ?

Answer (score 0):

here is the proper way to set timezone in php

refference:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_default_timezone_set.asp

Comment: this function is for php, can set timezone for mysql too ?

Comment: no this is only for php, but you can use date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

if database time change required. you can do like this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484965/how-to-set-database-time-zone-in-application-ini?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

7e-5 is 0.07 *nanoseconds*!

In PHP, I like to use `microtime(true)`.

I don't know where you got `microseconds()`.

If that is supposed to be a MySQL command, it will take much longer than a nanosecond, possibly close to a millisecond.

Comment: Thanks, you right, when I formatted the output with `sprintf` I watch that was a milisecond :) the result was `0.0000770`

Comment: .07 ns is a super result considering that a clock cycle @ 3GHz takes .33 ns to complete ...